# Cannot Insert, Identity insert off

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This seems so simple, yet I can't get it work. I have two tables, `Organization` and `Season`.

The `Organization` table can have an active season set, the season must be created with an `Organization` set.

`Organization` class (table)

```
public class Organization
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Active Season")]
    public int? ActiveSeasonID { get; set; }

    public virtual Season ActiveSeason { get; set; }
}
```

`Season` class (table)

```
public class Season
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int OrganizationID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Organization organization { get; set; }        
}
```

Gives me this error:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'ResultzSys.DAL.Organization' and 'ResultzSys.DAL.Season'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

So I have this to define the relationship between the two

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Organization>()
        .HasOptional(s => s.ActiveSeason).WithRequired(d => d.organization);
```

but when I try to add a Season I get

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Season' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Controller code that throws that error:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "ID,OrganizationID,StartDate,EndDate,Name")] Season season)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ResultzContext()));
        var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        season.OrganizationID = currentUser.OrganizationID;
        db.Seasons.Add(season);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

I simply don't understand why it won't let me create the season record... Any hints are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I guess there should be an attribute for this kind of columns. searching...

Answer (score 0):

According to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx), you should use [`DatabaseGenerated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute on your identity columns:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity)] 
public int ID { get; set; }
```

Comment: Yes, worth trying of course, although the same article points out that "by default, a key property that is an integer will become an identity key in the database. That would be the same as setting DatabaseGenerated to DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity" so I guess it won't make much difference?

Comment: You are right. Hope this one works, however I found another solution for plan B!

Comment: Take a look at this approach. I don't know if it can be applied to your situation, but better than nothing: http://www.i-avington.com/Posts/Post/how-to-set-an-identity-column-using-code-first-for-entity-framework-in-the